# Format data for polyline in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, format

I am currently trying to use this variable with this format for polylining;

```
 var flightPlaneCoordinates = [
        {
            lat: 69.772,
            lng: -122.214
        },
        {
            lat: 21.291,
            lng: -157.821
        },
        {
            lat: -18.142,
            lng: 178.431
        },
        {
            lat: -27.467,
            lng: 153.027
        }
    ];
```

I am generating data with Python and Google Maps API and receives this output;

> [(59.91624, 10.75972), (59.91591, 10.75947), (59.91578, 10.75933),
>   (59.91545, 10.75906), (59.91559, 10.75855), (59.91589, 10.75761),
>   (59.91612, 10.75709), (59.91618, 10.75697), (59.91628, 10.7571),
>   (59.91631, 10.75702), (59.91456, 10.75295), (59.9115, 10.74973),
>   (59.91166, 10.73282), (59.9148, 10.71855), (59.91785, 10.70705),
>   (59.91929, 10.69771), (59.92186, 10.68772), (59.92227, 10.67894),
>   (59.91803, 10.66188), (59.91555, 10.6492), (59.91319, 10.63807),
>   (59.90658, 10.6289), (59.90319, 10.62671), (59.90316, 10.6268),
>   (59.90309, 10.62668), (59.90291, 10.6264), (59.90285, 10.62657),
>   (59.90268, 10.62693), (59.90263, 10.62697), (59.90256, 10.62699),
>   (59.90247, 10.62697), (59.90216, 10.62649), (59.90203, 10.62633),
>   (59.90186, 10.62623), (59.90163, 10.62622), (59.90137, 10.62626),
>   (59.90097, 10.62633), (59.90085, 10.62634), (59.90071, 10.62632),
>   (59.90068, 10.62638), (59.9006, 10.62641), (59.90041, 10.62651),
>   (59.90015, 10.62678), (59.89995, 10.62707), (59.89971, 10.6274)]

How can I format this to the same format that is in (var flightPlaneCoordinates)? I would love to be able to do this in Javascript if that is possible. My first question here, thanks alot guys!

Comment: Can you replace the round brace with square brace [[59.91624, 10.75972]]

Comment: Yes I can do that in python, does it help with the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If your generated data is in the following format:

```
let data = [
    [59.91624, 10.75972], [59.91591, 10.75947],
    [59.91578, 10.75933], [59.91545, 10.75906]
];
```

You can transform it in desired format with `.map()` like this:

```
let result = data.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat, lng}));
```

**Demo:**

```js
let data = [[59.91624, 10.75972], [59.91591, 10.75947],[59.91578, 10.75933], [59.91545, 10.75906]];

let result = data.map(([lat, lng]) => ({lat, lng}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It is using map

```js
var polyline = [[59.91624, 10.75972], [59.91591, 10.75947], [59.91578, 10.75933], [59.91545, 10.75906], [59.91559, 10.75855], [59.91589, 10.75761], [59.91612, 10.75709], [59.91618, 10.75697], [59.91628, 10.7571], [59.91631, 10.75702], [59.91456, 10.75295], [59.9115, 10.74973], [59.91166, 10.73282], [59.9148, 10.71855], [59.91785, 10.70705], [59.91929, 10.69771], [59.92186, 10.68772], [59.92227, 10.67894], [59.91803, 10.66188], [59.91555, 10.6492], [59.91319, 10.63807], [59.90658, 10.6289], [59.90319, 10.62671], [59.90316, 10.6268], [59.90309, 10.62668], [59.90291, 10.6264], [59.90285, 10.62657], [59.90268, 10.62693], [59.90263, 10.62697], [59.90256, 10.62699], [59.90247, 10.62697], [59.90216, 10.62649], [59.90203, 10.62633], [59.90186, 10.62623], [59.90163, 10.62622], [59.90137, 10.62626], [59.90097, 10.62633], [59.90085, 10.62634], [59.90071, 10.62632], [59.90068, 10.62638], [59.9006, 10.62641], [59.90041, 10.62651], [59.90015, 10.62678], [59.89995, 10.62707], [59.89971, 10.6274]]

var translated = polyline.map((item) => {return {lat:item[0],lng: item[1]}})

console.log(translated);
```